# How do I handle multiple AWS accounts in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've read up on Terraform and using AWS S3 and DynamoDB for sharing state and locking. My problem is that we have multiple AWS accounts, by which I mean multiple sign-in locations like:

- https://account1.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
- https://account2.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

Is it better to have separate S3 and DynamoDB instances in each account, or should we have a single location that's used across all of them?

Comment: We keep it separate. Each account has an S3 and DynamoDB for its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is highly dependent on what you put inside it, if the states are only account related I'd go with a separate S2/dynamodb per account, if the states are cross-account then you'd need a central place to record them.